# How to pass string variable with square brackets?

Tags: python, string, pandas

> df1

```
                 model        horsepower
1                  I30        
2                 CR-V        
3        BMW 5 [F10] 13
```

> df2

```
                 model        horsepower
1            I30 15-17        100
2             CR-V 15-        130
3    BMW 5 [F10] 13-18        200
```

My goal is to find horsepower from df2 for each car model in df1:

```
for i,row in df1.iterrows():
    var = row['model'] 
    score = df2.loc[df2['model'].str.contains(var)]['horsepower'].item()
    df1.at[i,'horsepower'] = score
```

I have a problem with this car model:

> "BMW 5 [F10] 13-18"

Square brackets messes up the data and I get the error:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Everything works fine for all other models (tested on more over 100).
only BMW model messes thing up.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide `df1` and `df2` or their sample rows.

Comment: Perhaps `df1` and `df2` do not have the same index and size? You are using the index from `df2` to look up in `df1`.

Comment: The square brackets are definitely not your problem.

Comment: `df1.at[i,horsepower] = score`
where `horsepower` should be `'horsepower'`

Comment: thx, I corrected horsepower. I`ve changed it manualy to simplyfy the example. The error remains

Comment: indexes are fine. It works properly. As long there is no model with brackets. This particular model messes things up

Comment: `BMW 5[F10] 13` in df1 is not in df2->`BMW 5 [F10] 13-18`, see the space between `5` and `[`

Comment: corrected that, sorry - my example had to be changed to simplyfy.